# Won't run ajax if I change input type..?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form for user to update their info using jquery + Ajax. Everything is working great so far, but WHen i change input type="email" to input type="text" in the fullname section of the form and click update. It got error??? It won't run the php file in ajax. I don't see any connection which causes this error? Anyone please sugguest why? But if I change input type in the fullname section back to "email". It works! This is so weird!

Here is my form:

```
 <div id="changeuserinfo_result"></div>
    <form role="form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fullname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="changename" name="changename" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="changepass" name="changepass" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pass'] ?>">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="changeuserinfo">Update</button>
                </form>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#changename').focus();  
$('#changeuserinfo').click(function(){ 
    var changename = $('#changename');  
    var changepass = $('#changepass');
    var changeuserinfo_result = $('#changeuserinfo_result'); 
    changeuserinfo_result.html('loading...');
    if(changename.val() == ''){ 
        changename.focus();
        changeuserinfo_result.html('<span class="errorss"> * Empty fullname</span>');
        return false;
    }
    else if(changepass.val() == ''){ 
        changepass.focus();
        changeuserinfo_result.html('<span class="errorss">* Empty password</span>');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var UrlToPass = {changename:changename.val(),changepass:changepass.val()} ;
        $.ajax({ 
        type : 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data : UrlToPass,
        url  : 'changeuserinfo.php',
            success: function(responseText){ 
                if(responseText == 1){
                    $('#changeuserinfo_result').html('<span style="color:green"> Update OK</span>');
                }
                else{
                    $('#changeuserinfo_result').html('<span class="errorss"> Update fail. Try again</span>');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code to codepen and it worked perfectly. Have you checked the browser console to see if you have any javascript errors? With an error it might not execute the post part of the js at all.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl F5 for refreshing cache?

Comment: i tried to clear cache and everything but it does not work. I tried to test with chrome and firefox, still same result. Tested with firebug, it just quickly show the the red line of the + POST http://..../changeuserinfo.php and disappear. My code is working just fine if i change the input type="text" from the fullname to input type="email".

Comment: Are there any other javascript functions running? One could overtake the action involving using inputs of type "text"

Comment: it works for chrome but didnt work for firefox if input type ="text". But if i change input type ="email". It works for both

Comment: As @n-dru asked, what error are you getting ? Isn't the page called, or what ?

Comment: in firebug i got this error:  `red line of the + POST http://..../changeuserinfo.php ` Then it disappear from the console, I can't click to see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have no closing tags on your inputs.

It should be `<input type="text"... />`

Also set the doctype of the page to HTML5.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
....
</html>
```

Comment: did the closing tag but still does not work and i have set doctype correctly to html5.

Comment: Closing tags are irrelevant for the question and no longer required in HTML5